# Get all posts ID showed in a page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Given a page (can be the front page or a SERP too) I need to get all IDs of the posts listed: I need to create an array with these IDs.

There is any way to take something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily create an array from the post_ids of all the posts rendering on the page.
Here is code below, you can find:

```
<?php $ids = array();
while(have_posts()): the_post();
$ids[] = $post->ID;
endwhile;
?>
```

Now, you can easily use the 'ids' array anywhere on the same page, just like this:

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ids);
?>
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you and let me know, if you have any query. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Right answer.